# SQL query to select from multiple tables and create third table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can someone please help me with a SQL query? My apologies if a similar question has been asked before.
Finding it difficult from other examples I have seen.

I have 2 tables and would like to create a third table.

Table - advisories

```
advID | productName         
    1 | 3.4/3.5/3.6
    2 | 3.4
    3 | 3.5/3.6
```

Table - customerA

```
hostname | version      
A        | 3.3
B        | 3.5
C        | 3.6
```

Final Table

```
hostname | advID    
A        | NULL
B        | 1
B        | 3
C        | 1
C        | 3
```

Does this look correct?

```
select advId, productNames, hostname, version 
from advisories, customerA
where productNames 
like '%3.6%';
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never use commas in the FROM, if you want a cross join, use `cross join`

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: Please provide a MRE as described in the wiki info for the second tag you used. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info

Comment: This is an inappropriate data model. Don't store multiple values in one string, when you are interested in the separate values. As to your query: Comma-separated joins (`from advisories, customerA`)  are a relict from the 1980s. Use explicit joins instead. You'd need an outer join (show customers plus their advisories if any), which is something along the lines of `from customerA c left join advisories a on a.productname like '%' || c.version || '%'`. But this has issues. `like '%3.6%'` matches `3.65` and `13.6` for instance. Fix your data model. Only then write the query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Please consider making an answer. (Or maybe allow "fresh and ambitious" tag participants to flesh your comment out into an answer.)

Comment: @Yunnosch: Go ahead :-) I don't have the time at the moment to write an answer. If you (or anybody for that matter) want to do this, do it please.

Comment: Thanks. Not necessarily me however, I was thinking of others (and maybe me....).

Comment: Thanks all for the pointers. I have created SQL fiddle if that helps in answering. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae36bae/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `LIKE` in the `JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT C.HOSTNAME,
       A.advisoryId
  FROM customerA C LEFT JOIN advisories A
ON CONCAT('/',A.productNames,'/') LIKE concat('%/',C.version,'/%')
order by C.HOSTNAME
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae36bae/18). I have changed the `||` to `CONCAT` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. could please use SQL fiddle to answer?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae36bae/11

Comment: Check the answer now, with SQL Fiddle